# Alternatives to OmniPlan

Tags: macos

I have used [OmniPlan](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniplan/) for a 6 month project with lots of tasks and people. I like the visual appearance really much, but its drag'n'drop is annoying to use when you drag tasks outside the scrollview and it starts scrolling. The scrolling makes it impossible to position the tasks correct on my 27" display.

Any alternatives?  And how is the scrolling?  Price doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Merlin](http://www.projectwizards.net/en/merlin/)

Comment: Really fast to work with. I like it.